# How to set custom date to DatePicker of react-datepicker using MomentJS?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-datepicker

I have stored dates in database. I can fetch dates successfully. But when it comes to set any particular date to DatePicker of [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker), I couldn't set that date.

Here is code that I have used for fetching dates and setting state with the value of date.

```
loadAllEvents() {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/SelectAllDatesFromDb',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {},
    }).then(function (response) {
        if(response!=null){     
            this.setState({
                eventList: response.data
            });
            this.updateAllDates();
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                eventList: []
            });
        }

    }.bind(this))
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

UpdateAllDates() function for converting dates using [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com)

```
updateAllDates() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.eventList.length; i++) {
            var items = this.state.eventList;
            items[i].event_date = moment(this.state.eventList[i].event_date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
            this.setState({ eventList: items });    
        }
    }
```

After getting dates, now I try to set date to datepicker and try to set `selected` parameter. Here is code:

```
<InputGroup>
  <DatePicker
    className="form-control"
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    maxDate={new Date()}
    isClearable={true}
    selected={this.state.eventList[0].event_date}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    disabled={this.state.eventDateBox}
    showYearDropdown
    showMonthDropdown
  />
```

When I runs code I get error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'event_date' of undefined`:
[image]

Where am I making mistake? Is there any other way of setting a date to DateTimePicker with default/custom date?

Comment: Are you sure that the state is set when you try to access it? Since I can't see your entire component, make sure you've actually set the state at the time you're trying to access it, you could try something like: selected={this.state.eventList ? this.state.eventList[0].event_date : "")

Comment: Ok. I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`updateAllDates` will be called only after the successfull API call. So by the time the page renders your `this.state.eventList[0]` will be undefined.

So have a check like the below

```
{ this.state.eventList[0] &&
<InputGroup>
  <DatePicker
    className="form-control"
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    maxDate={new Date()}
    isClearable={true}
    selected={this.state.eventList[0].event_date}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    disabled={this.state.eventDateBox}
    showYearDropdown
    showMonthDropdown
  />
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, now it's throwing `RangeError: Invalid time value` error. This might be because of converting that date format with the help of momentjs. I have converted it to Javascript compatible date format, then also it didn't work.

Comment: convert it into new Date(this.state.eventList[0].event_date)

Comment: I have tried it. It still throws `RangeError: Invalid time value` error.

Comment: Can you post it as a separate question as it is out of scope of this question I will try to work your new question

Comment: How out of scope. I mean it's part of this same question.

Comment: `{ this.state.eventList[0] &&` what does this line mean? I didn't get it. I never used this before. Can you tell me the reason?