# Throwing error RangeError: Invalid time value while setting custom date to DatePicker of react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, react-datepicker

I'm trying to set selected parameter as default date of DatePicker of [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker). Basically date which I'm getting from database is in following format:

`event_date: "2019-06-15"`

and when I set state, that date shows in this way - `event_date: "2019-06-15T00:00:00"`

I have tried to `new Date()` for converting it into JavaScript compatible date. Also tried [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) but then also it's throwing same error. When I call `new Date()` in `selected` parameter then everything works perfectly. I mean, DatePicker shows default todays date. But when I try to set custom date value to DatePicker, it throws error - `RangeError: Invalid time value`.

Can anyone tell me what type of data DatePicker need for setting custom date?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems your date is in `string` format. `Datepicker` don't accept string date.

You need to parse the string date to actual date using [parseISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-beta.2/docs/parseISO)

```
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns'
```

Usage,

```
parseISO(your_custom_date)
```

Comment: I would consider it an unnecessary overhead to import something solely for a purpose that can be achieved with vanilla JS methods.

Comment: @ravibagul91 it still didn't work. It still showing same error.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly but you haven't passed 'DD/MM/YYYY' to `format()` function in your demo.
Below is your code 
`items[i].event_date = moment(this.state.eventList[i].event_date).format();` 

Below is my code 
`items[i].event_date = moment(this.state.eventList[i].event_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');`
Check I have edited your code... It has thrown error.

Comment: Yes. I haven't pass the format, because Datepicker need date in format `2019-06-15T00:00:00` (Date with Time) and doing ` moment(this.state.eventList[i].event_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')` will only give date and not time, so the error for time.

Comment: You can directly avoid `updateAllDates` function. Because date from DB is in correct format but a string, you just need to parse that string date to actual date.

Comment: That code has set custom date. But how can I change date now as in selected attribute I have - `selected={this.state.eventList && this.state.eventList.length > 0 && parseISO(this.state.eventList[0].event_date)}` . How can I track date selected by user?

Comment: this crap of tool does not know how to convert dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 6):

React-datepicker requires an instance of `Date` to be passed for configuration values such as `startDate`, etc. (or possibly it also excepts timestamp integers, not sure).

You can use

```
new Date(Date.parse("2019-06-15T00:00:00"));
```

To create a date instance. [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) recognizes many date string formats and converts them to timestamp values which in turn are accepted by the `Date()` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. But I have issue, when I try to parse value using `Date.parse()` which is converted from momentjs, it throws `RangeError: Invalid time value`. I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592478) - for successful API call. But it's working only for single index 0. Do I need to use state instead of single index?

Comment: Can you show an example of value that fails with Date.parse()?

Comment: Value that fails is in format of DD/MM/YYYY e.g. 22/08/2019

Comment: Problem is that either I can convert date with `momentjs` or I can convert date with `Date.parse()`. I couldn't convert both dates at once. What would be the problem?

Comment: You showed one example date string format in the question and never mentioned you're dealing with various formats. My answer was valid in that regard.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use latest date-fns library in Javascript and use below for format

```
import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns' 

format(parseISO(DateinISOformat), "MMM dd h:m a")
```

Example below -

```
format(parseISO('2019-06-15T00:00:00'), "MMM dd h:m a")
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns"; 
<div>{format(parseISO(dateofbirth, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()), "do MMM yyy")}</div>
```